# Error Message but still debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I don't have the code for this.My problem is that when I input text have an error the program is not responding anymore and I need to close the program and edit my code.What I want is that when there is an error there is this message that would say that this part of code is error and no need for me to close the program.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide some more additional details like Error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to capture the execption with a try-catch block and either save the error to a log or display it on the screen

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Oops, somthing bad happened!"); //This is line 17
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            //throw; //If you don't have this the code will continue executing after this point.
        }
    }
}
```

When this program is run the following message box is shown

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
System.Exception: Oops, somthing bad happened!

   at Sandbox_Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Sandbox Console\Program.cs:line 17
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

See how it shows on line 17 a error happened, you can save that information to a log file too for later reading.